# Cascading Dropdown List: Some error is coming

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have made 3 lists(City,District,Ward). Then, i did cascading dropdown of lists i.e city & District. Cascading is working fine. When we select city, then accordingly district is comin. Now, if try to select another city accordingly district comes but, it also includes some integer value of previous selected district in dropdown list.

Can anyone help me please to sort out this problem?

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: I have done cascading dropdown using Infopath, I have used below mentioned link: https://basquang.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mATsK0aVZ9I  , this video will help you achieve what you are looking for, it is more detailed then the link you provided. I used the video to achieve what you are looking for.